# How to highlight cells in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you highlight cells in an HTML table by letting the user select them -- just like you would do in Excel?

Here are 3 samples that show what I mean: [image]

Comment: You can make use of JavaScript to do that. To save the selected cell positions, use localStorage.

Comment: great, Mehul -- please show me how

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the possibility:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

And JavaScript:

```
function toggleBG() {
   if(this.className.indexOf("yellowBG") >= 0) {
      var x = this.className;
      this.className = x.split("yellowBG").join(''); 
   } else {
      this.className += "yellowBG";
   }
}
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].addEventListener('click', toggleBG,, false);
}
```

And CSS:

```
.yellowBG {
   background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply a CSS class when a user clicks on a cell. You could remove the class upon a second click.

Try this:

```js
// Wait until the DOM is loaded
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Get all the td elements in an array
  var theCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  
  // Loop through each td
  for(var i = 0; i < theCells.length; ++i){
    
     // Set up a click event handler for the td
     theCells[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       
       // Check to see if the td has the class attribute applied already
       if(this.getAttribute("class") === "highlight"){
         // If so, remove it
         this.removeAttribute("class");
       } else {
         // If not, add it
         this.setAttribute("class", "highlight");     
       }
     });
  }
  
});
```

```css
td{border:1px solid black;}
.highlight {background:#ff0;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```